# pyautoGUI を Mac にインストールしたがインポートできない

Tags: python, python3

Python のライブラリ pyautoGUI を使いたく、ターミナルでインストールまでは完了しましたが、インポートができません。
`import pyautogui` とコマンドを実行しても、"command not found" とエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

原因を探しているのですが、お分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたく思います。よろしくお願いします。

(pyobjc-core、pyobjc、pillowはインストール済みです)

■使用しているパソコン
macOS Catalina
MacBook Pro 
バージョン10.15.4

■使用しているPythonのバージョン
3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

出ているエラーの全文は `-bash: import: command not found` でしょうか。

その場合はまずターミナルで`python`などを打ち込んで、インタプリタを立ち上げてから`import pyautogui`を実行する必要があります。

もしくは`./hoge.py`などのコマンドでpythonスクリプトを直接呼び出していないでしょうか。
その場合もpython用のコマンドと認識されずにエラーとなる場合があります。
下記のリンク先を参考にして`#!/usr/bin/env python3`などのshebangをつけるか、`python ./hoge.py`のようにpythonの引数としてスクリプトを実行してください。

[他サイトの類似回答](https://teratail.com/questions/115694#reply-175837)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。いただいたアドバイスをもとにインタプリタを立ち上げ、実行しましたところ、うまくいったようです。ありがとうございました。